# how to render chemical formula using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i'm trying to export some data to  Excel using apache poi 3.9 , but the title of the data should use a standard chemical formula  like SO<sub>2</sub> but not SO2 ,i have been serachcing answer for a long time, but still dont resolve this problem . can somebody help me ? i will be appreciated !

Comment: The "2" must probably be done with a different font with sub- resp. superscript. [Font.setTypeOffset](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setTypeOffset-short-)

Comment: Answer your own question with the solution you found, so the question may be marked solved.

Comment: Use XSSFRichTextString. You can use cell.setCellValue to set that cell's value to be the XSSFRichTextString value. XSSFRichTextString can be built up using 'append' calls where each append can have its own XSSFFont - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html#append-java.lang.String-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont-. Or you can use XSSFRichTextString.applyFont. See Joop Eggen's comment about how to create Fonts with subscript. With fonts, reuse the font instances because Excel has limit on the number of fonts instances it supports.

Comment: What about simply `cell.setCellValue("SO\u2082")`? Unicode provides superscripts and subscripts by code points - https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf. So no rich text needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.